# Dynamic SVG container added to iFrame in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am wondering if it is possible to build a SVG container in a external JS file and then appendChild to the already created iFrame container by ID. I got it to the point where I see that the SVG container has been added into the iFrame container when I inspect in the dev browser window. However, when I get to the point where I append the function that will draw the SVG it says that it cannot append to a null element. Now I know that usually this error is because the DOM is not fully loaded before it is appended but I can see it in the dev browser window. One thing that is curious is that when I hover over the elements in the dev browser window I can see that my iFrame and SVG have dimensions but my g container I am adding has dimenions 0x0 as well as my function that is inside my g container. I dont have any experience with JQuery so I would like to avoid using it if possible.

Here is some of the JS code so I can post the rest will be here https://jsfiddle.net/7jovqt1n/13/

`

```
function addDiv() {

  var block_to_insert;
  var svg_to_insert = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
  var g_to_insert;

  block_to_insert = document.createElement('div');
  block_to_insert.setAttribute("id", new_id);
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("id", "root");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("width", "480");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("height", "600");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 96 96");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet");
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("xmlns", svgNS);
  svg_to_insert.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
  block_to_insert.appendChild(svg_to_insert);
  g_to_insert = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
  g_to_insert.setAttribute("id", "window");

  svg_to_insert.appendChild(g_to_insert);

  document.getElementById("svgImage").appendChild(block_to_insert);
}
```

`
I have tried creating a seperate HTML file and setting my iFrame src equal to that file and then calling onload equal to my dynamic SVG creation function in the body. But the error persists, I am wondering is this even possible?

Comment: setAttributeNS to set xlink and xml attributes.

Comment: Why the IFRAME? You can [load an external SVG into shadowDOM or as inline element](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this needs to run from a webserver. Running it from the filesystem does not work. Displaying an external SVG document can either be done using `<iframe>` or `<object>`. In both cases the SVG document must have the same origin as the HTML document. If not, `document` will be `null` as you have experienced.

Make sure that both the HTML document AND the SVG document has been loaded before starting to request the DOM. Here you have a simple example:

#### HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        // call the iframe by its name
        frame01.addEventListener('load', e => {
          let svg = e.target;
          svg.getElementById('c1').setAttribute('fill', 'ForestGreen');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe name="frame01" width="300" height="200" src="svg.svg"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### SVG document (svg.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle id="c1" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="Orange" />
</svg>
```